# Tiling + OpenGL texture flipping

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to convert tiling rendering from SDL2 to OpenGL. Here is the image from SDL2;

[image: SDL2 rendering]

And the same image rendered using OpenGL without texture flipped in Y-axis;

[image: OpenGL with no texture flipping]

And here is the image from OpenGL rendering with texture flipped in Y-axis;

[image: OpenGL with texture flipped]

Where should I compensate the coordinates with a Y-flipped texture and to get it rendered properly in the OpenGL coordinate system? Here is the code I used to get the texture uv's to render the second picture(texture not flipped) and third picture(flipped texture) in OpenGL;

```
glm::vec4 srcRect;
srcRect.x = (float)((tileLayer->GetTileId(x, y) - (tileY * tilesPerRow))* (tileWidth+ spacing) )/imageWidth;
srcRect.y = (float)(tileY * (tileHeight + spacing)+ margin)/imageHeight;
srcRect.z = (float)tileWidth/imageWidth;
srcRect.w = (float)tileHeight/imageHeight ;
```

Comment: If I understand rightly, then you have problems with only y-axis. Try to use this line for y: `srcRect.y = (float)(imageHeight - tileY*(tileHeight + spacing) - margin)/imageHeight`/

Comment: @Danil, thanks for the reply. I just tried your suggestion but still failed (http://imgur.com/DCIrJeE.png).

Comment: OK, what about this `srcRect.y = (float)(tileHeight - tileY*(tileHeight+spacing) - margin)/imageHeight` or `srcRect.y = (float)tileHeight - (float)(tileY*(tileHeight+spacing) + margin)/imageHeight`?

Comment: @Danil, thanks. Just tried them both, also failed. Do you think that it's not just the coordinate system that should be flipped, but also the pixels? If that's the case, then I guess I will have to find other ways to flip the whole image. Any suggestion for that if that's the case? Thanks.

Comment: in OpenGL y-axis directed to up. In other system y-axis maybe directed to down. Maybe this is cause of problem.

Comment: It must be possible with a combination of inverting both your pixel coordinates and vertical tile offsets, but perhaps it's faster and easier to flip the original images with an image editor ... If I am correct, then you don't need to change your code at all.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, I would go just by creating perspective transformation with flipped y, and with coordinates matching the screen size, like (D with gl3n): mat4.orthographic(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1). OpenGL math libraries use same principle like e.g. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml - edit: I write this an answer in case it helps you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't understood the problem correctly, just ignore this post. If I understood the problem correctly, instead of tweaking ready-made graphics and computations in working code, I would alter OpenGL perspective transformation to match SDL. OpenGL does not have any preference to coordinate system, so you can tweak it freely to suit your purposes.

I assume you are using modern OpenGL (programmable shaders, no fixed pipeline) and some OpenGL math library (e.g. glm for C++). Most libraries have ortho() to create orthographic perspective with coordinate transformation. The syntax is:

```
glm::ortho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
```

Just flip bottom and top, and you get flipped y. For 2D graphics, near and far fields can be close anything, as your objects all have zero as z coordinate:

```
glm::ortho(
    -1,  1,    // X goes -1 to 1
     1, -1,    // Y goes 1 (at bottom!) to -1 (at top!)
    -1, 1)     // -1 < 0 < 1
```

But you can get better. Use your window size parameters, and you can use regular pixel-based coordinates (instead of -1 ... 1 range):

```
glm::ortho(
    0, width,   // X goes 0 to width
    height, 0,  // Y goes 0 (top) to height (bottom)
    -1, 1)      // near & far
```

To make it with fixed pipeline (old OpenGL), use glOrtho().

Hope this was the problem, and if it was, hope this helps.

EDIT: Just in case... You can tweak perspective transformation even more to suit better tile based 2D games. Lets say your "unit size" of objects is like 32x32 (sprites, background tiles, etc). To get rid of multiplying and dividing with sprite width & length (converting map array indexes to screen coordinates and vice versa), just match coordinate "unit size" to tile size:

```
glm::ortho(
    0, width / tile.width,    // +1 X is +tile.width
    height / tile.height, 0,  // +1 Y is +tile.height
    -1, 1)                    // near & far
```

EDIT (see comments): Lets assume you use ortho(0, width, height, 0) to get "traditional" screen coordinates in pixels. To blit 32x32 bitmap to window, you have following rectangle constructed from two triangles:

```
uv (0, 0)               uv( 1, 0)
pos(0, 0)              pos(32, 0)
     +-----------------+
     |A               D|
     |                 |
     |B               C|
     +-----------------+
pos(0,32)              pos(32, 32)
uv (0, 1)              uv ( 1,  1)
```

Default winding is counter-clockwise (triangles ABC, CDA). "Reference" point can be also changed to center, using rectangle (-16, -16) - (16, 16). Furthermore: you can use "unitbox" (0,0)-(1,1) or (-0.5,-05)-(0.5,0.5), and scale it up to correct dimensions with model matrix you pass to shader. This allows you to easily use same box to blit textures in any sizes.

If you don't like to alter perspective, you can also do flipping by turning the rectangle you use to blit "upside down", and scaling the positions down to 32/width and 32/height (e.g. in model matrix). This affects to winding, so you may need to tweak face culling parameters (glCullFace, glFrontFace, glPolygonMode).

But IMO it is much more convenient for 2D graphics to tweak perspective and continue using "default" window coordinates you have used to use. 3D side is different beast.

Comment: I'll accept your reply as the answer as it is indeed a valid workaround. Isn't it a flipped OpenGL texture was supposed to get srcRect calculation right and without change with the SDL's version except the normalized values in the OpenGL uv space? Or was it my understanding is wrong in that regard? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmh, yes, indeed, this is bit more hairy than just flipping perspective, as this also involves coordinates of the rectangle you use to blit the texture.. So, you can also do flipping by turning rectangle "upside down" - I add explanation of this to my answer in a second. But UV coordinates are normalized anyways :D

Comment: I wrote some sort of description about the polygon you use to blit the texture. In OpenGL, you have many different locations you can tweak coordinates: you can use any of the transform matrices (model, view perspective), or you can do tweaks when setting up polygon. I just personally would prefer changing perspective to match the one that was used in original SDL code: it is the way SDL (at top of OpenGL) most probably has originally flipped coordinates to give you "traditional" coordinate system.